# Vue 2.7.13 - How to write onClick correctly in tsx

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, tsx

```
vue version 2.7.13
```

it is support jsx but when i use onClick have a type error

```
Type '(event: MouseEvent) => Promise<void>' cannot be assigned to type 'MouseEvent'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I write this code correctly

Comment: Hi, code images are not allowed here. Please rewrite it with actual text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-on:click` for getting event correctly when using vue

```
 <div v-on:click="clickWallet">Click me</div>
```